# Any other selection method other than freehand with Photoshop's patch tool? (CS6)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, photo-editing

I have found that the Patch Tool is really useful for certain healing situations, but I can't stand that it is only freehand drawn. Is there a way to use a click-move-click-move-click selection method (like to polygonal lasso tool)?

I'm using CS6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the polygon lasso to create your selection. While the Patch tool is a freehand only, any selection can be used as a patch selection.

Comment: Dang that seems now as extremely obvious. :)